# Explore the convergence of a series with ln

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

How to explore the convergence of this series:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\ln^n(n+1)}
$$

What would be better to use: De Lamber indication or feature comparison.
And if comparison is a good choice, what should I compare ???

Sorry for my English!
Thanks

Comment: your latex(?) is broken. please fix.

Comment: As it is your question is practically impossible to understand. Fix it, please.

Comment: I think it's mathematica code

Comment: @user126540 you are right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by $\ln^n(n+1)$ you mean $(\ln(n+1))^n$, then the obvious choice is the root test.
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{\ln^n(n+1)}}=\ ?
$$

Comment: The limit equal zero. 0 < 1, so the series is convergent. Right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: thanks from Ukraine to Basque Country

Answer (score 1):

If you know that geometric series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n$ converges for $|x| < 1$ than you can use series comparison test for positive series by comparing terms to $1/(\ln 3)^n$.